# Finding only duplicates in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I'm looking to sort some data by looking at a column and only returning rows that have a duplicate value within a certain range in that column (between 10-600 duplicates). When I use the count function I can see, for example:

```
fruits | count
-------+------
apple  |    15
banana |    23
orange |    19
```

The code I have correctly shows all the fruits that have between 10-600 duplicates, but I want to see every row of duplicates. So I want to see the 15 apple rows, 23 banana rows and 19 orange rows, except in my case there are thousands of "fruits" I need to break it down by so just singling out each one isn't an option. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window` functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by fruit) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt between 10 and 600;
```

Comment: @alessiocantarella . . . My formatting rules are explained in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel, Second Edition".

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to this so it may seem dumb, but what does t refer to? the dataset name? Right now my code looks like this:    ----------                                          select dataset.*
 from (select dataset.*,
      count(*) over (partition by fruit) as cnt
     from dataset
    ) dataset
where cnt between 10 and 600;
and date > DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
AND country = 'US' -------  it's not working, is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: @Jason . . . `t` is a shorthand for the table and alias used for the data.  It isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html)

```
create table fruits (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(255));

insert into fruits (name) values ('apple'), ('banana'), ('orange'),
('apple'), ('banana'), ('orange'),('apple'), ('banana'), ('orange'),
('apple'), ('banana'), ('orange'), ('pear');

select
    id,
    name
from (
    select
        count(*) over (partition by name) as total,
        id,
        name
    from fruits
) as t
where t.total >= 1 and t.total <= 6;
```